# How to check for combined RowState 'Altering | Edit' in RowDataBound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, rowstate

On my page, I set up a GridView with a few columns. I coded an update, delete and insert method. While my GridView binds its data, the following method is called:

```
protected void GridViewAutomat_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Edit)
        { 
            //some code

        }
    }
}
```

The Problem with my second if statement is that when my GridView is entering the Edit Mode (when I want to update a record in my GridView) it doesn't catch the `RowState` **Alternate | Edit** which looks like this(this is how the RowState is after I call my Update Method):

[image]

When I try to combine the two RowStates separately it wont work either:

```
if(e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Edit && 
   e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Alternate)
```

The Code in the if-statement should be executed when the row is not in edit (**Alternate | Edit**) mode, that's why I have `!=` as an operator

Does anyone know how I can catch the combined mode **Alternate | Edit** and the Edit Mode together?

Comment: with which rowstate you want to  work?

Comment: i want to check the rowstate for Alternate | Edit & plain Edit mode. So my Programm doesnt execute any code in my if statement when i try to update a record @Asif.Ali

Comment: Its in Alter | Edit when i click on edit

Comment: so you want to check if its not in **Edit** or **Alter | Edit** mode?

Comment: exactly, thats what im looking for

Answer (score 4):

You can check it in:

- **Edit** mode:

  ```
  e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Edit
  ```
- **Alter | Edit** mode:

  ```
  e.Row.RowState != (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate)
  ```

In workaround:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
    e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Edit && 
    e.Row.RowState != (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate))
{ 
    //... Here is logic
}
```

Or:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Edit && 
        e.Row.RowState != (DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate))
    {
        //... here is logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `RowState` value is a [`DataControlRowState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowstate?view=netframework-4.8) enum, which has the `Flags` attribute set.  This means we can call [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=netcore-3.1), like so:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow &&
    e.Row.RowState.HasFlag(DataControlRowState.Edit))
{ 
    //... Here is logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers already provided already are probably easier to read for human beings who don't use a lot of bitwise operators on a day to day basis.  However, an alternative would be to use a [binary logical AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators) `&`, leveraging that [RowState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowstate) is a bitwise property:

```cs
        if (!((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0))
        { 
            //some code - Executed when RowState is NOT Edit
        }
```

Note that the example snippet above runs the code block when the row state is NOT in Edit mode in accordance with the original poster's situation.  If you need to execute code when the row state IS in Edit mode, simply remove the `!` negation, i.e. `if (((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0))`.

Credit to one of the responses on [this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ffadf72e-78f3-43bd-b4ad-019b64ae8a74/erowrowstate-datacontrolrowstateedit-only-works-on-alternating-rows?forum=aspwebformsdata) that led me to this solution.